# I am new to tkinter and sql.connector but this error keeps popping up idk what to do

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I ran this function

```
def query(q):
    conn = sqltor.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd=password, database='Bark_n_Purr')
    cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    query_result = cursor.execute(q)
    conn.commit()
    return query_result
```

which is later called in this function

```
def submit():
    if len(e_pid.get()) == 0 or len(e_pname.get()) == 0 or len(e_custname.get()) == 0 or \
            len(e_phnum.get()) == 0 or len(e_address.get()) == 0:
        mb.showinfo('!', 'You need to fill out all details!!!')
    else:

        q = 'insert into vet_log values(', v_count, ',"'+str(package)+'",'+e_pid.get()+';'
        query(q)
        popup.destroy()
```

but this error shows up

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tejju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 486, in cmd_query
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tejju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/Python/cs group project/main.py", line 86, in submit
    query(q)
  File "E:/Python/cs group project/main.py", line 13, in query
    query_result = cursor.execute(q)
  File "C:\Users\tejju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "C:\Users\tejju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 499, in cmd_query
    errno=2055, values=(addr, 'Connection not available.'))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available.
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You might want to repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Since your posted code doesn't execute, and you haven't included the lines causing the problem, and you haven't tried to trace the problem, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: The error message is clear, as far as it goes: `query` is a tuple.  We have no idea why it's a tuple, or what you're trying to do with your assumption that it's a string of appropriate content.

Comment: The error message says that connection is not getting established

Comment: nvm converting the format made it work

Comment: the program is actually all inegrated within itself and if i had to post I woukd have to post the whole program

Answer (score 2):

If you call `print(q)` after the following line:

```
q = 'insert into vet_log values(', v_count, ',"'+str(package)+'",'+e_pid.get()+';'
```

You will get a tuple instead of a string.

Try changing to:

```
q = 'insert into vet_log values ({}, "{}", {});'.format(v_count, str(package), e_pid.get())
```

Comment: currently the problem isnt the format of the query I'm running, Its that the connection doesnt establish

Comment: No the error said when the first exception (tuple error) is being handled, another exception (connection error) is caught.  That means the tuple error is the first exception.